# How do you create a new Case using On Demand Email-to-Case upon forwarding the case to a new Email-to-Case?

Tags: case, servicecloud, email2case

I'm working in an org that's requesting a new case be generated whenever an Email-to-Case is forwarded to another department which also happens to be an Email-to-Case email. This means that 2 cases be created should the original Email-to-Case need to be forwarded.

To clarify, you receive an Email-to-Case through support@inbox.com. You, the agent, can't help with this issue, but the tech support team can - so you forward the incoming email to another Email-to-Case called techsupport@inbox.com. At this point, a new case should be created.

Seems simple, but Salesforce's default behavior is to keep it as a single case identified by the threadId. Tried a few things, but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve your requirement:-

1. You can achieve the requirement by writing trigger on EmailMessage object on afterinsert event.
   You will have to make some customization to the email sent by support agents to tech support agents so that its easily identifiable technically as well as with naked eye to say with confidence that this email is a forwarded email and should create a new Email-To-Case record. Thus from there you can create an Email-To-Case record via code.
2. Using Email Service you can write custom apex code to create Email-To-Case record. You will have to add a forwarding address in techsupport@inbox.com so that each email to this address goes through the email service apex class code. Here you can determine whether to create a new Email-To-Case record or just attach the email to an existing case record.

Both approach are code intensive and can't be done just by some configuration.

However, the entire requirement of having two same case record in same org is not good and shouldn't be implemented from architectural standpoint as it will lead to further complications down the line like data sync, storage, processing and performance.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a trigger?